# How to add dynamic path to the single-spa-router path attribute in single spa react application

Tags: html, reactjs, single-spa, base-path

We have a code like this.

**microfrontend-layout.html**

```
<single-spa-router base="/">
  <main>
    <route default>
      <h1>404 route not defined</h1>
    </route>
</main>
</single-spa-router>
```

I would like to add a dynamic value to the '`base`' attribute. How can we achieve this?

Comment: I glanced at the documentation and I did not see any indication that routes can be dynamic in nature.  If you need dynamic routes, drop the router and use single-spa API only.  This way you'll be able to provide an activity function that returns true with any arbitrary logic you want or need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking for the same solution, couldn't find it. But I kind of solved with "System.import" parcels based on window.location.

mine is for tab UI, hope it helps

```
import Parcel from "single-spa-react/parcel";
const [parcels, setParcels] = useState(remoteHash);
    
      const updateParcelsWithModule = (module, endpoint) => {
        setParcels((prev) => {
          const newParcels = prev.map((parcel) => {
            if (parcel.endpoint === endpoint) {
              return {
                ...parcel,
                module: module,
                isRendered: true,
              };
            }
            return parcel;
          });
          return newParcels;
        });
      };
    
      useLayoutEffect(() => {
        System.import("//localhost:9000/js/app.js")
          .then((module) => {
            updateParcelsWithModule(module, endpoint);
          })
          .catch((err) => console.error(err));
      }, [activeTabKey]);
    
      if (!parcels) return <></>;
    
      return (
        <div className="flex-auto h-0 overflow-auto">
      
          {parcels?.map((parcel) => (
            <div
              key={parcel.endpoint}
            >
              {parcel?.module && (
                <Parcel
                  config={parcel?.module}
                  wrapWith="div"
                  wrapStyle={{ height: "100%" }}
                />
              )}
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      );
    };
```